# What is Freestyle chaining?

Tags: freestyle

In the Freestyle render settings under the *Freestyle Line Style* rollout there are a group of settings having to do with *chaining*.

[image]

I have played around with these settings in a number of ways and haven't really found any noticeable impact on the render.  So what is chaining and what does it do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Consider the lines as "a whole" or "individually"

As reported in the [manual](https://www.blender.org/manual/render/freestyle/parameter_editor/line_style/strokes.html#chaining), "chaining" is a parameter that controls the way in which lines are rendered.

If enabled, Blender will draw each line as if it was connected with the previous; on the other way, if disables, it will render each line **separately**.

You can see the effect by increasing line thickness and zoom in till you can see where one line ends and another starts:

[image]

While the same object with chaining enabled is:

[image]

---

It is useful to make custom line styles. Notice in the examples below how the same thickness modifier brings to different results:

[image]

[image]